# vba excel: using dynamic array in seperated workbook which is created from template

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, report

I grabbed some information from my db, showed them in listbox in a userform and populated them in array named lsarr() which has dynamic rows and static columns.
Now I want to use this array in report workbook which is separately saved as in reports folder. firstly a template is prepared by dynamic rows of array then report is saved as to new workbook by specific name.
everything works fine until lsarr() wants to copied to a range in exported workbook. When i call lsarr() i receive a message

> sub or function not defined

codes are as following:

```
Private Sub cusbas_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
...............
...............
lsarr = soldtable.List
...............
...............
end sub
```

this works fine

```
Private Sub sales2templ_Click()

    Dim outpath As String
    Dim curdate As String
    Dim repno As String
    Dim xl3 As Object
    Dim twb2, wb3 As Workbook
    Dim i, j, k As Integer

    Set xl3 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl3.Visible = True
    xl3.Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\Report-Sales.xltx"
    Set twb2 = xl3.ActiveWorkbook
    twb2.Sheets("Sales-Report").Activate
    twb2.Worksheets("Sales-Report").Range("C1").value = custlbl

        If totalinvpercust > 2 Then
                For i = 1 To totalinvpercust - 2
                    twb2.Sheets("Sales-Report").Range("A7:G7").EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Insert
                Next i

                    For j = 1 To totalinvpercust
                    twb2.Sheets("Sales-Report").Range("A" & j + 6).value = j
                Next j

                For k = 0 To totalinvpercust - 1
                twb2.Sheets("Sales-Report").Range("B" & j + 7).value = lsarr(0, k)

                Next k

        Else
            twb2.Sheets("Sales-Report").Range("A7").value = 1
            twb2.Sheets("Sales-Report").Range("A8").value = 2
        End If

    'On Error Resume Next
    repno = frm_salesrev.cusbas.Text
    curdate = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddHhNnSs")
    outpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Reports\report" & "-" & repno & "-" & curdate & ".xlsx"
    twb2.SaveAs Filename:=outpath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, AccessMode:=xlExclusive

    xl3.ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized


     Set twb2 = Nothing
     Set xl3 = Nothing
     Set xl2 = Nothing
     curdate = ""
     outpath = ""
end sub
```

the problem occurs in

```
twb2.Sheets("Sales-Report").Range("B" & j + 7).value = lsarr(0, k)
```

*** both subs are in the same module***

Comment: Where have you defined `lsarr ()`?

Comment: in first sub: dim lsarr() as variant  redim lsarr(cuschk,6) as variant

Comment: Well there's the problem. You need to pass that variable to the other function to use it there, which you cant do because it's a Click event.

Answer (score 0):

Dim the variable outside of the subroutine to make it a form/module level variable instead like this:

```
Dim lsarr() as Variant

Private Sub cusbas_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  Redim lsarr(cuschk,6)

  ...............
  ...............
  lsarr = soldtable.List
  ...............
  ...............

End Sub
```

Comment: great ! it woked! previously I moved it to the first line of sub that was not effective!